# Mandrill not sending message

Tags: laravel, curl, mandrill

I have been trying to send a mail using Mandrill.

And when I try to send a mail like this:

```
Mail::send('emails.sample',[], function ($message){
    $message->subject('Message Subject');
    $message->from('noreply@example.net', 'Sender Name');
    $message->to('anEmail@example.com'); // Recipient address

    return 'sent';
});
```

I get Error  cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate". I have done a lot of google and checked on stackflows but there seems to be no stated out solution.Some post on solutions online suggests i ignore that warning and give cURL the -k or pass it the insecure param, and that am not sure on what to do.Any help please

Comment: What version of Laravel?  What is the "driver" key set to in your `app/config/mail.php` file?

Comment: version 4.2 with driver set as mandrill

Comment: Do you have the guzzle 4 package installed and your secret key set in `app/config/services.php`?

Comment: Have you set the certificates and certificate bundles correctly for your server. Do not pass any certificate checks with `-k` or `false` or somesuch. Verify that you've got a working SSL/TLS certificate and a curl CAINFO file installed for your server. http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on WAMP windows. This is due to guzzle using SSL. Following was the fix for me

1. Download [this archive](https://gist.github.com/VersatilityWerks/5719158/download) and extract the cacert.pem file (I've put it in wamp\bin\php).
2. Add/uncomment `curl.cainfo =<.pem file folder>\cacert.pem` to php.ini

Source: [laracasts.com](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file : \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Transport\MandrillTransport.php

and add this line of code :

```
public function send(Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$failedRecipients = null)
{
    $client = $this->getHttpClient();
    $client->setDefaultOption('verify', false); // ***add this***
    $client->post('https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-raw.json', [
        'body' => [
            'key' => $this->key,
            'raw_message' => (string) $message,
            'async' => false,
        ],
    ]);
}
```